# how to get last id when a row was insert in laravel eloquent in Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've used **setNotification** method of model by initial data from Controller within a variable **$data** as array. I have used self:: in this method instead of used table or **Notification::save()** or **$obj->save()**. by this way I don't know how to get Id which the last id after insert was done in laravel because I used $this->attributes that it is the protected variable in Model.

```
class Notification extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'notification';
    public $timestamps = true;
    private $_data = false;


    public function setNotification($data)
    {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $this->attributes = $data;
            self::save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `$this->attributes[id]` after `save()` is executed.

Comment: This is work return $this->last_id = self::getQueueableId();

Answer (score 1):

I suggest You to use `create` method instead and return created object, so then You can access `id` property.

```
public function setNotification($data)
{
   if (is_array($data)) {
        return $this->create($data);
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: `$notification = new Notification();`  
`$object = $notification->setNotification($data);`  
`dd($object->id);`

Comment: I assuming that You are creating new `Notification` object in controller and then call `setNotification` method.

Comment: No I refer to return id in this method instead of call that obj in controller.